# Specifying a subset of optional template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have a template class like

```
template<class FooPolicy=DefaultFooPolicy, 
  class BarPolicy=DefaultBarPolicy, 
  class BazPolicy=DefaultBazPolicy> HighlyCustomizableClass;
```

Now I declare some typedefs:

```
typedef HighlyCustomizableClass<AlternativeFooPolicy> VersionA;
typedef HighlyCustomizableClass<DefaultFooPolicy,AlternativeBarPolicy> VersionB;
typedef HighlyCustomizableClass<DefaultFooPolicy,DefaultBarPolicy,AlternativeBazPolicy> VersionC;
```

This can get unwieldy, especially if we have even more template parameters. Furthermore, if another `Policy` type is added to `HighlyCustomizableClass`, then existing `typedef` statements become invalid. This doesn't seem necessary.

It'd be much nicer to be able to write these as:

```
typedef HighlyCustomizableClass<FooPolicy=AlternativeFooPolicy> VersionA;
typedef HighlyCustomizableClass<BarPolicy=AlternativeBarPolicy> VersionB;
typedef HighlyCustomizableClass<BazPolicy=AlternativeBazPolicy> VersionC;
```

Is it possible in theory for c++ to allow this syntax? If so, are there any plans for future standards to adopt it? If not, is there some reason why this sort of syntax would be problematic?

Comment: You can emulate this using C++11 template aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported syntax in C++ is

```
typedef HighlyCustomizableClass<FooPolicy<AlternativeFooPolicy>> VersionA;
```

The idiom is called named template parameter and can be implemented with help of [Boost Parameter Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html). If you don't like boost you can look at [C++ Templates The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.de/tmplbook/index.html) 16.1 Named template arguments. [Source code](http://www.josuttis.de/tmplbook/inherit/namedtmpl.cpp.html) is available.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exaclty what you'd like, but with template aliases in C++11 you can say

```
template<
   class foo=def_foo, 
   class bar=def_bar, 
   class baz=def_baz
> custom;

template<class foo=alt_foo>
using VersionA = custom<foo>;

template<class bar=alt_bar>
using VersionB = custom<def_foo, bar>;

template<class baz=alt_baz>
using VersionC = custom<def_foo, def_bar, baz>;
```

I've taken the liberty to make names shorter :-)

Template parameters are identified by their position in the parameter list (just like function parameters) and not by their name (like attributes of HTML elements, for instance)!.